# Splitting line of text into array at bash

Tags: arrays, bash, ifs

I have a bunch of files named `jtn216_<n>.o<m>` where `n` and `m` are integer. The first one is assigned by me and the second one by the system. I need to check the last line at each file. I ran this to split that line into array

```
for i in {361..380}; do 
  v=$(tail -n 1 jtn216_$i.o*)
  IFS=' ' read -ra line <<< "$v"
  echo $line $v 
done
```

> 3499200 3499200 87650.5574975270 13.6931802555886
>   1014400 1014400 87947.4382620423 13.9208064005841
>   3475800 3475800 87779.1695691355 13.8939964916376
>   3479200 3479200 87459.7284508034 13.7824644675699
>   3827800 3827800 87868.7538056652 13.8792123626210
>   2551600 2551600 87615.6417285010 13.8700006744178
>   3818400 3818400 87872.1788028955 13.8942371285402
>   3476800 3476800 87842.0543708163 13.9170342642747
>   3481800 3481800 87670.5841054385 13.8808556469308
>   2559200 2559200 87800.6530231416 13.8874423695824
>   3841600 3841600 87804.3972028423 13.8657419719638
>   916400 916400 87776.1342228681 13.8622746230494
>   3839000 3839000 87662.8185016707 13.8576498806465
>   3835200 3835200 87933.6917697832 14.0007327053153
>   3482000 3482000 88323.3509854563 13.9453990979062
>   3485400 3485400 87657.5078357100 13.8478805156354
>   3484800 3484800 87757.3379321554 13.8215034461609
>   3475400 3475400 87970.4729449120 13.9605031841208
>   3481800 3481800 87612.4211302676 13.8327950845915
>   2319400 2319400 87521.5669854330 13.8383953325475

I expected `line` to be an array not the first value from `v`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you want to do. What would the expected output be?

Comment: $fedorqui I expect ``line`` to be the array ``[3499200, 87650.5574975270, 13.6931802555886]`` (I'm not certain how array are written in bash).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're just printing `line` wrongly. Try `echo "${line[@]}"` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Please fix your answer to "${line[@]}" for future references.

Answer (score 3):

You should address the contents of the array variable $line well e.g.

```
echo "${line[0]}"
echo "${line[*]}"  # converts to a single string
echo "${line[@]}"  # converts to multiple elements i.e. multiple arguments for echo
```

When an array variable is addressed without an index it would be just equivalent to getting the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, if you want to get last line as array:

```bsh
v=(`tail -n 1 jtn216_$i.o*`)
```

**UPDATED**

To accumulate `line` as array use:

```
v=(`tail -n 1 jtn216_$i.o*`)
line+=(${v[@]})
```

To output whole array:

`${line[@]}` or `${line[*]}`

To count number of array elements:

`${#line[@]}` or `${#line[*]}`

Comment: Thanks. My bash foo is very low.

Answer (score 1):

What bash calls "arrays" are really just a list of words (a list that can't even be nested). So if you simply output the array using `echo`, you're just asking it to output a list of arguments to echo. Consider:

```
echo foo bar # 'foo bar\n'
echo -n foo bar # 'foo bar'
x=( -n foo bar )
echo "${x[@]}" # 'foo bar'
```

If you output an array's name without any index or @ or * component, you will get the first word* in that array:

```
echo "$x" # foo
```

So when you do `echo $line $v` what you're really saying is

```
echo ${line[0]} $v
```

Here's what you probably want:

```
for i in {361..380}; do 
  tail -n 1 jtn216_$i.o* | { # Pipe to a compound command to preserve assignments from read
    IFS=' ' read -ra line
    printf '[ '
    printf '%s ' "${line[@]}"
    printf ']\n'
  }
done
```

Then you should see

```
[ 3499200 87650.5574975270 13.6931802555886 ]
[ 1014400 87947.4382620423 13.9208064005841 ]
[ 3475800 87779.1695691355 13.8939964916376 ]
…
```

*Wordsplit *again* since you didn't use quotes.